# Clarification of Solution of PDE Laplace Transform Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

I have the following problem:

> The transverse displacement $u(x, t)$ of a semi-infinite elastic string satisfies
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{t}^2} = c^2 \dfrac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}$$
>
> for $x > 0$, $t > 0$,
>
> with initial conditions
>
> $$u(x, 0) = \dfrac{\partial{u(x, 0)}}{\partial{t}} = 0$$
>
> for $x > 0$,
>
> and boundary condition
>
> $$-\beta \dfrac{\partial{u(0, t)}}{\partial{x}} = f(t)$$
>
> for $t > 0$.
>
> Show, using Laplace transforms, that the solution can be written
>
> $$u(x, t) = \dfrac{c}{\beta} H \left( t - \dfrac{x}{c} \right) \int^{t - x/c}_0 f(u) \ du,$$
>
> where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. Can you interpret this result physically?

And I have the following solution:

> Taking the Laplace transform of the PDE yields
>
> $$s^2 \mathcal{L} \{u\} - su(x, 0) - u_t(x, 0) = c^2 \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \}$$.
>
> Substituting the initial conditions gets us
>
> \begin{align} &s^2 \mathcal{L} \{ u \} = c^2 \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} \\ 
> &\Rightarrow \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{s^2}{c^2} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} \\ 
> &\Rightarrow \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} - \dfrac{s^2}{c^2} \mathcal{L} \{u(x, t) \} = 0 \end{align}
>
> We solve this homogeneous second-order linear DE:
>
> \begin{align} &m^2 - \dfrac{s^2}{c^2} = 0 \\
> &\Rightarrow m = \pm \dfrac{s}{c} \end{align}
>
> Therefore, the general solution to this DE is
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = A(s) e^{x\frac{s}{c}} + B(s)e^{-x \frac{s}{c}},$$
>
> where $A(s)$ and $B(s)$ are arbitrary functions.
>
> To apply the boundary conditions, we differentiate the general solution with respect to $x$:
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c}e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \dfrac{sB(s)}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$
>
> And since we had the boundary condition
>
> $$- \beta \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} u(0, t) = f(t),$$
>
> we have
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(0, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} - \dfrac{sB(s)}{c}$$
>
> Taking the Laplace transform of the boundary condition, we get
>
> $$- \beta \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(0, t) \} = \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}$$
>
> So we get
>
> \begin{align} &-\dfrac{\mathcal{L} \{f(t) \}}{\beta} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} - \dfrac{sB(s)}{c} \\
> & \Rightarrow -\dfrac{\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}}{\beta} = \dfrac{s}{c}(A(s) - B(s)) \\
> & \Rightarrow \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{ \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}}{s} + A(s) = B(s) \end{align}
>
> Using this to eliminate $B(s)$ from the general solution leaves
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{ \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}}{s} + A(s) \right) \dfrac{s}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$
>
> We can now constrain $A(s)$ by using the initial value theorem with the initial conditions:
>
> \begin{align} 0 &= u(x, 0) \\
> &= \lim_{t \to 0} u(x, t) \\
> &= \lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} \end{align}
>
> for all $x > 0$.
>
> Using the general solution, we see that
>
> $$\lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \lim_{s \to \infty} A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}} s,$$
>
> since $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = 0$ means that $\lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \} = 0$.

I'm confused about this last part:

> Using the general solution, we see that
>
> $$\lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \lim_{s \to \infty} A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}} s,$$
>
> since $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = 0$ means that $\lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \} = 0$.

I don't see how they got

$$\lim_{s \to \infty} s \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \lim_{s \to \infty} A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}} s$$

?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to mention that you forgot the $\mathcal{L}$ symbol at some places:

> So we get
>
> \begin{align} &-\dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{\beta} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} - \dfrac{sB(s)}{c} \\
> & \Rightarrow -\dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{\beta} = \dfrac{s}{c}(A(s) - B(s)) \\
> & \Rightarrow \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) = B(s) \end{align}
>
> Using this to eliminate $B(s)$ from the general solution leaves
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) \right) \dfrac{s}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$

Now we can show the equation. Substituting the expression for $B(s)$ in $\mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\}$ and multiplying with $s$ gives
$$ s\mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = s A(s) \left(e^{\frac{sx}{c}}+e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}\right) + \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}.  $$

From the boundary condition $f(t) =-\beta \frac{\partial u(0,t)}{\partial x}$ for all $t>0$, and the initial condition $u(x,0)=0$ for all $x>0$, it follows that $\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)=0$. Then the initial value theorem implies $\lim_{s\to\infty}s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=0$. This and the fact that $x$, $s$ and $c$ are positive implies that.
$$\lim_{s\to\infty} \frac{c}{\beta} \frac{s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}=0.$$

---

**Edit:** As was pointed out by The Pointer in the comments (pun not intended), it suffices to note that $\lim_{s\to \infty} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=0$ (asymptotic property of Laplace transforms) and that the constants are positive.

---

Since $\lim_{s\to\infty} \mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\} = 0$ (asymptotic property of Laplace transforms), also $\lim_{s\to\infty} A(s)=0$, and thus $\lim_{s\to \infty} A(s) s e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}=0$.

We conclude that
$$\lim_{s\to \infty} s \mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\} = \lim_{s\to\infty }s A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}}.$$

I hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't it be $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) \right) \dfrac{s}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}} \Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{1}{\beta} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} + \dfrac{s}{c} A(s) \right) e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $s$, we get $$s\mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{s^2}{c} A(s) \left( e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - e^{\frac{-sx}{c}} \right) - \dfrac{s}{\beta} \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$

Comment: I think the expression for $s\mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\}$ is correct. You forgot to take the factors $\frac{s}{c}$ in account when integrating with respect to $x$. (But please, do correct me if I am wrong, I didn't write down the calculations on paper, so a typo or missing constant quickly gets in.)

Comment: Hmm, integrating? I didn't integrate anything, nor did I realise this problem required any integration? My work above is just from using algebra from $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{ \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}}{s} + A(s) \right) \dfrac{s}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$.

Comment: If you want to get $\mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\}$ from $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\}$, you need to integrate with respect to $x$, right? (Note that the Laplace transform is done with respect to $t$.) Or alternatively, just put $B(t)$ in the expression of $\mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\}$ you have on top.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. I actually made an error. So you integrated $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = \dfrac{sA(s)}{c} e^{\frac{sx}{c}} - \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) \right) \dfrac{s}{c} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$ with respect to $x$, but that would give $$ \mathcal{L} \{ u(x, t) \} = A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}} + \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) \right) e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$ But I think you forgot the the $-1$ factor, which gives rise to the term [...]

Comment: [...] $$+ \left( \dfrac{c}{\beta} \dfrac{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} + A(s) \right) e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}$$ ?

Comment: Is that all right? Or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are right, one minus sign is wrong. I will edit this. Thank you for noting this.

Comment: I think it's misleading to state that it is implied that $$\lim_{s\to\infty} \frac{c}{\beta} \frac{s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}} = 0.$$ This is vacuously true, due to (1) the algebra of the expression itself and (2) the properties of limits: $$\lim_{s\to\infty} \frac{c}{\beta} \frac{s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}}{s} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}} = \lim_{s\to\infty} \frac{c}{\beta} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}} = 0,$$ but the previous facts that you specify (except for the facts that $x, s, c > 0$) are not required for this statement to be true.

Comment: And I still don't see how it is valid to conclude that $$\lim_{s\to \infty} s \mathcal{L}\{u(x,t)\} = s A(s) e^{\frac{sx}{c}}.$$ This doesn't seem to follow from anything you've previously stated?

Comment: @The Pointer. Indeed, in hindsight I see that this argument is way too long. About your second remark. I forgot the $\lim$ in the right hand side.

Comment: Ahh, ok, now it makes sense to me. Thank you for the clarification! :)

Comment: And also thank you very much for helping with correcting my typos!

Comment: Hmm, hold on, I think what I wrote might be incorrect. If $\lim_{s\to \infty} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = 0$, then $$\lim_{s\to \infty} \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} e^{-\frac{sx}{c}} =  \dfrac{0}{0}$$, since $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \ dt$$?

Comment: No, it's $0\cdot 0 = 0$, right?

Comment: Hmm, please elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83831/discussion-between-ernie060-and-the-pointer).

Comment: Absolutely correct, it should be $0 \times 0$! My mistake!

Comment: Thank you again for your kindness, Ernie!